# How can I resolve the error "installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10"

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gdm

How can I resolve the package installation error of the gdm3 package?

I got an error message whenever I install Debian packages by using apt;

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up gdm3 (42.0-1ubuntu7) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
gdm3
```

I have tried to resolve the error as follows but failed.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gdm3 (42.0-1ubuntu7) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The gdm3 package was re-installed in TTY mode, but the error still exists.

Anyone who knows the solution, please gives me a hint.

Regards

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. It's the first thing to try in cases like this. At the very least, it will give you a more elaborate error message.

Comment: As you see in the original post, I have already tried to ```sudo dpkg --configure -a```
It gives the message, " installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10"